# Erro com proteção de senha no laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estou criando um sistema com laravel, e usando só a api dele.
Codigo da API:

```
Route::get('/teste', function (Request $request) {

    $nick = '@mesa0'. rand(11, 50);
    $number = '0'. rand(11, 50);
    $password ='123456';
    $password_confirmation ='123456';

    $data = ['nick'=>$nick,'number'=>$number,'password'=>$password,'password_confirmation'=>$password_confirmation];

    $validate = Validator::make($data, [
                'nick' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:desks',
                'number' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:desks',
                'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);

    if ($validate->fails()) {
        return ['status' => false, "validacao" => true, "erros" => $validate->errors()];
    }

    //return $data;

    $desk = Desk::create([
                'nick' => $nick,
                'number' => $number,
                'password' => bcrypt($password)

    ]);
    $desk->token = $desk->createToken($desk->nick)->accessToken;

    return ['status' => true, "mesa" => $desk];



  //  return Desk::all();
});
```

Arquivo Desk, no diretório App/

esse é o arquivo que determina a tabela, estou usando sqlite

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;



class Desk extends Model
{
     use HasApiTokens,
        Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'nick', 'number',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
         'remember_token','password'
    ];
}
```

e essa é a migração

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateDesksTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('desks', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('nick',255)->unique();
            $table->string('number',255)->unique();
            $table->string('password',255);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('desks');
    }
}
```

o erro é esse:

```
"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: desks.password (SQL: insert into "desks" ("nick", "number", "updated_at", "created_at") values (@mesa014, 029, 2019-02-19 01:22:03, 2019-02-19 01:22:03))"
```

quando eu não defino 'password' como atributo protegido "protected $hidden", funciona normalmente, mas quando protejo ele da ess erro. Não achei como resolver.

Answer (score 0):

Bem, resolvido, dentro do Model Desk, implementei o atributo **password** para os protegidos e para os normais. o Erro parou e a senha não é retornada.

```
protected $fillable = [
        'nick', 'number','password'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
         'remember_token','password'
    ];
```